# datetime column mismatch while exporting from csv to mysql

Tags: mysql, csv

I am newbie to c# and trying to export csv file to mysql  table where i get this wrongly formatted datetime column.

```
my csv file is datetime is : 21/03/2014 14:49:06.
mysql datetime column is : 2014-03-21 14:49:06.
MySql datetiem after exporting :0000:00:00:00
```

My code is : .

`string strLoadData = "LOAD DATA LOCAL  INFILE 'E:/finalcode.csv' INTO TABLE turnover  FIELDS  terminated by ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'  lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (SiteId,DateTime,Serial,DeviceId) SET DateTime = STR_To_DATE(DateTime,'%yyyy-%MM-%dd %H:%i:%s')";`

Comment: Is datetime of type datetime or is it varchar column?

Comment: type datetime in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Your input to datetime columns is

> *21/03/2014 14:49:06*

It is in the format `'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'`. You have to let MySQL engine understand that it is in that format. So that MySQL converts input date value into acceptable format using proper `datetime format string`.

**Change**:

```
SET DateTime = STR_To_DATE( DateTime,'%yyyy-%MM-%dd %H:%i:%s' )
```

**To**:

```
SET DateTime = STR_To_DATE( DateTime,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s' )
```

Comment: I have tried that Ravinder  but still the same results.

Comment: 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in datetime column in mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use below sytanx:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL  INFILE 'E:/finalcode.csv' INTO TABLE turnover  FIELDS  TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (`SiteId`,@val,`Serial`,`DeviceId`) SET `DateTime` = STR_TO_DATE(@val,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s');
```